# OLS Rolling regression in Python Error - IndexError: index out of bounds

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, statsmodels

For my evaluation, I want to run a rolling for example of 3 window `OLS regression estimation` for a dataset found in [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Iv8dfU4fTUMVFyYTEtWXlzYkk) (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2Iv8dfU4fTUMVFyYTEtWXlzYkk) as in the following format. The third column (Y) in my dataset is my true value - that's what I wanted to predict (estimate).

```
 time     X   Y
0.000543  0  10
0.000575  0  10
0.041324  1  10
0.041331  2  10
0.041336  3  10
0.04134   4  10
  ...
9.987735  55 239
9.987739  56 239
9.987744  57 239
9.987749  58 239
9.987938  59 239
```

Using a simple `OLS regression estimation`, I have tried it with the following script.

```
# /usr/bin/python -tt

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('estimated_pred.csv')

model = pd.stats.ols.MovingOLS(y=df.Y, x=df[['X']], 
                               window_type='rolling', window=3, intercept=True)
df['Y_hat'] = model.y_predict

print(df['Y_hat'])
print (model.summary)
df.plot.scatter(x='X', y='Y', s=0.1)
```

However, using either `statsmodels` or `scikit-learn` seems to be a good choice for something beyond the simple regression. I have tried to make the following script work using `statsmodels` but returing an `IndexError: index out of bounds` with higher subset of the [attached](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2Iv8dfU4fTUMVFyYTEtWXlzYkk) dataset (for example for more than 1000 rows of the dataset).

```
# /usr/bin/python -tt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm


df=pd.read_csv('estimated_pred.csv')    
df=df.dropna() # to drop nans in case there are any
window = 3
#print(df.index) # to print index
df['a']=None #constant
df['b1']=None #beta1
df['b2']=None #beta2
for i in range(window,len(df)):
    temp=df.iloc[i-window:i,:]
    RollOLS=sm.OLS(temp.loc[:,'Y'],sm.add_constant(temp.loc[:,['time','X']])).fit()
    df.iloc[i,df.columns.get_loc('a')]=RollOLS.params[0]
    df.iloc[i,df.columns.get_loc('b1')]=RollOLS.params[1]
    df.iloc[i,df.columns.get_loc('b2')]=RollOLS.params[2]

#The following line gives us predicted values in a row, given the PRIOR row's estimated parameters
df['predicted']=df['a'].shift(1)+df['b1'].shift(1)*df['time']+df['b2'].shift(1)*df['X']

print(df['predicted'])
#print(df['b2'])

#print(RollOLS.predict(sm.add_constant(predict_x)))

print(temp)
```

Finally, I want to do a prediction of `Y` (i.e. predict the current value of `Y` according to the previous 3 rolling values of `X`. How can we do this using either `statsmodels` or `scikit-learn` for `pd.stats.ols.MovingOLS` was removed in `Pandas` version 0.20.0 and since I can't find any reference?

Comment: Can you report the full Trace of the error?

Comment: Sure. Here is the full trace of the error. `File` is for new line: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../Desktop/rolling_regression/rolling_regression2.py", line 26, in <module>
    df.iloc[i,df.columns.get_loc('b2')]=RollOLS.params[2]
  File "../anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 1986, in get_value
    return tslib.get_value_box(s, key)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 777, in pandas.tslib.get_value_box (pandas/tslib.c:17017)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 793, in pandas.tslib.get_value_box (pandas/tslib.c:16774)
IndexError: index out of bounds`

Comment: It looks like the call to sm.OLS was successfull. Please check/show RollOls.params to be sure it actually has 3 entries.

Comment: Yeah it does. It actually works only for few rows of the dataset (for example: 500 rows) - the `IndexError: index out of bounds` error occurs when i try it with higher subset of the dataset (let's say 1000).

Comment: What I can suggest is using %debug and "u" to go up the trace, so you can see if the error occurs when you do: RollOLS.params[2]  or when you do df.iloc[i,df.columns.get_loc('b2')]    .
Anyway the error is occuring at the last line of the loop and it is an error related to accessing with wrong index, it is not related to sm.OLS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found your problem:
from the [documentation](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tools.tools.add_constant.html#statsmodels-tools-tools-add-constant) of `sm.add_constant`, there is an argument called `has_constant` that you need to set to `add` (the default is `skip`).

> has_constant : str {'raise', 'add', 'skip'}
>       Behavior if ``data'' already has a constant. The default will return
>       data without adding another constant. If 'raise', will raise an
>       error if a constant is present. Using 'add' will duplicate the
>       constant, if one is present. Has no effect for structured or
>       recarrays. There is no checking for a constant in this case.

Essentially for that iteration of the loop your variable `time` was constant in the subset, hence the function did not add a constant and as a result RollOLS.params had only 2 entries.

```
temp
Out[12]: 
        time   X     Y      a           b1           b2
541  0.16182  13  20.0  19.49      3.15289 -1.26116e-05
542  0.16182  14  20.0     20            0  7.10543e-15
543  0.16182  15  20.0     20 -7.45058e-09            0

sm.add_constant(temp.loc[:,['time','X']])
Out[13]: 
        time   X
541  0.16182  13
542  0.16182  14
543  0.16182  15

sm.add_constant(temp.loc[:,['time','X']], has_constant = 'add')
Out[14]: 
     const     time   X
541      1  0.16182  13
542      1  0.16182  14
543      1  0.16182  15
```

So the error is going away if you had `has_constant = 'add'` in the `sm.add_constant` function, but you would have two linearly dependent columns in the explanatory variables, which makes the matrix not invertible hence the regression would not make sense.

Comment: Thank you FLab. I still can't understand why it was working only for example 100 rows of the dataset without the error though. What do you mean by `but you would have two linearly dependent columns in the explanatory variables, which makes the matrix not invertible hence the regression would not make sense`? I thought `df['a']` was the constant in my script.

Comment: I think at index 541-543 is the first time when time is constant over 3 observations.   On the second point, look at the last output of the snippet code. Essentially you have time = 0.16182 * const, so the rank of your matrix is 2 (not 3). This problem is called multicollinearity (perfect, in this case): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity

Comment: aha, perfect and thank you. When we do `print(temp)` it only prints the last 3 predictions and how about it we want to print all of the predictions?

Comment: Do you mean all the predictions up to that point? You can retrieve them from df

Comment: Glad it helped. In general with OLS, your regression is: y = constant + b1 * time + b2 * x.   So, if you have a *new*  observation (t*, x*) you can estimate the value y* by plugging the values in the formula, using the coefficients you estimated using OLS. Now you are doing a rolling regression, so you re-estimate the coefficients. You typically do this to see if the relation between Y, time and X changes in time. On a side note, 3 observations looks like too much of a short sample to me to capture a stable relation.

Comment: sm.OLS returns an instance of this class, in particular you already have the predicted values and mse calculated for you: http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html